# Duda consulta SQL y api rest

Tags: sql, json, rest, postman

Buenos días estoy intentando consumir una api rest y entre los parametros que debo pasar está una consulta sql, el problema está en que hay un campo llamado "Account Manager_InternalId" así tal cual se llama con las comillas dobles y todo, acá está el json que estoy creando como entrada:

```
{
"sql":"SELECT jb.InternalId as codigo_orden, concat(emp.FirstName,' ',emp.LastName ) as Account_Manager,
sso.ActualShipDate as fecha, sso.\"BOL Notes\" as BOL_NOTES, jb.EntityStatus_Name ,jb.EntityStatus_InternalId as job_status ,
sso.Memo as memo,emp.MobilePhone, jb.DateCreated , sso.InternalId as codigo_orden_compra
FROM SalesOrder sso join Employee emp on sso.\"Account Manager_InternalId\" = emp.InternalId 
join Job jb on sso.Job_InternalId = jb.InternalId 
where sso.\"Account Manager_InternalId\" =xxx",
"pageSize":20
}
```

y el error que aparece es al consultar con postman es:

```
{
    "message": "Unknown column 'sso.Account Manager_InternalId'."
}
```

No me reconoce las `"` en todo caso.

Comment: ¿Cuál manejador de base de datos estás usando?

Comment: Nombres de tabla con espacios :/   por favor, indica  qué DBMS usas

Comment: Bueno no es un dbms como tal, se trata de netsuite

Comment: No puedes usar SQL sin un DBMS.

Comment: en resumen quiero que esta expresión \"Account Manager_InternalId\" cuando se envíe a la api quede asi "Account Manager_InternalId" para que me lo reconozca

Comment: Estaba revisando la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSTRW/NSTRW.pdf) de NetSuite y no veo que en SuiteQL se envíe un query como muestras en tu ejemplo. Qué versión usas?